# Best way to hide/don't load HTML-Parts based on configuration file?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to hide HTML-Elements based on value in a configuration file?

Example:
A user acess a HTML-File. If the configuration file contains something like "expert = "false"", the Browser shouldn't load the expert-div.

The HTML and Javascript should run on local PC(shouldn't need a Web-Server)

Comment: Best way to do this is PHP, otherwise the user could always be able to modify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if(config.expert === false){
  var expert = document.querySelectorAll('.expert'); // getting all elements with class expert

  for(var elmt in expert){
   elmt.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make config js file and check it's values in your html page

**config.js**

```
var expert = false;
var somethingElse = true;
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/config.js"></script>
<script>
    if(!expert)
        document.getElementById('expert').style.display = 'none';

    if(!somethingElse)
        document.getElementById('somethingElse').style.display = 'none';

    ...
</script>
```

just some basic idea.